# The importance of compactness

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Why the compactness of a metric/normed space and of a topology is so important as property ? 
I mean I understand the importance of completeness density and separability but I don’t see the point of the importance of compactness . Thanks

Comment: Continuous functions on bounded intervals attain their extrema which is nice. Also Bolzano-Weierstrass, Arzelà-Ascoli and Stone-Weierstrass work only on compact sets.

Comment: You may also want to read [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/371928/what-should-be-the-intuition-when-working-with-compactness), which also links to another similar question on math overflow.